# Once the button has been pressed, stop again.(Button not active/deactive)

Tags: c#

*Once the button has been pressed, stop again.
 Namely;
Once you have clicked on the button, click on how many clicks do not take action. The button must always be active*

Comment: Please specify your question more...

Comment: Looks like a copy-paste from some task but not a question. If you need some work to be done for you - you could use freelance sites instead.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfV7U.png

Comment: @BorisSokolov, I don't think that's the case. I guess the OP is just struggling using the English language. Kongsperfect, I got your point from the pic you posted. However, if you know that you're not good in English, I suggest that you -next time- ask one of your friends/colleagues to write the question for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use but maybe this is not a good idea

```
 string[] operators = new string[] {"+","-","*","/"};//all operators   
 private void Btn_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
          string str=yourtextBox.Text;
          string lastChar = str.Substring((str.Length - 1), 1);// get last caracter
          if (operators.Contains(lastChar))
             {

             }
          else
             {
              //your code
             }

        }
```